# LIBLINEAR and other SVM packages

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm using liblinear to classify a very large (~10M features) but sparse data. When using linlinear in C, it collapses. But the Python implementation works very well.

Has anyone had the same experience? What could be the reason? 
Are there more "efficient" and stable versions for SVM?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it collapses". Are you using the same set of parameters? The default values might not be same for both C and Python, however the underlying implementation is the same.

Comment: @Pedrom: Collapses mean that the script stops. Same parameters. I think it fails during the data loading proccess since when C it collapses when using 1.5GB (there are 32GB available) whereas in Python it load ~7GB to the memory.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code of both? Are you compiling the C++ version in 64bits?

Comment: @Pedrom: There isn't much code to share - just a command line. I'm using sklearn for Python. Do you want me to write it?
Also, I've tried a bigger data set and python also collapsed. That brings me to the question - are there "better" SVM implementations?